# MPMoviePlayerViewController not palying in ipod and iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
-(void)playVideo:(NSURL *)url{

    if (videoPlayer) {
        [videoPlayer release];
        videoPlayer = nil;
    }
    videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    url = nil;
    videoPlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    videoPlayer.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    videoPlayer.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    videoPlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];


    [videoPlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    videoPlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    videoPlayer.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    videoPlayer.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:videoPlayer animated:YES];

    [self addObservers];
}
```

Can anyone say what is wrong with this code? The url is streaming http link. Video player is appearing but after a while it disappears. It is working in 3G network but not in wifi

Comment: are you developing for 4.0 and above only?

Comment: yes it for 4.o and above..the interesting factor is video playing in 3G network but not in Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying that it was working on 3G but not on WiFi Network, your issue is most likely not related to the code but to the movie-file/s you are testing.

Make sure the m3u8-snippet is complete and valid also for low bandwidth. Test the m3u8 with Apples Mediastream Validator as described by this [Best Practice Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html) and this [Article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices).

Comment: thank You Til, the problem is with the wifi network, it  working fine in other WiFi connections, Thank you for remind the possiblities

Answer (score -1):

After this line:

```
videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
```

add this:

```
[videoPlayer retain];
```